# Callback after text field has been cleared

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'd like to execute code **after** the clear button of an UITextField has been tapped **and after** the text field has been cleared.

textFieldShouldReturn: is called **before** the text field is cleared.

textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: is not called at all when the clear button is tapped

The ultimate goal is that I am maintaining some graphical representation of the string being tapped in when it is tapped. I used textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: for that, and it works well, except when the clear button is tapped.
 (which should erase the graphical representation).

Comment: you do know when a clear is about to happen, since [`textFieldShouldClear:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:) is called.  Why not set a timer to run 0.1 seconds after returning `YES` from that delegate method and do whatever magic you wanted to do after the text field clears?

Comment: Thanks for that idea Michael. However, I dislike playing with timers, which always makes the debugging and maintenance more difficult. I up-voted Artal's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea: you can replace the system clear button with your own button. You'll need to handle clearing the text-field yourself (very simple) and then you can perform your custom animations and what not.

Create a button and set it as the `rightView` of your `UITextField`:

```
UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
clearButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 45);
clearButton.tintColor = myTextField.tintColor;
[clearButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MY_CLEAR_IMAGE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTextfieldClearButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myTextField.rightView = clearButton;
myTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

Handle the action:

```
-(void)onTextfieldClearButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton*)clearButton
{
    if([clearButton.superview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        ((UITextField*)(clearButton.superview)).text = @"";
        //TODO: YOUR MAGIC GOES HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea indeed. I take it ! Thanks.